# SD Card Reader Standards

Tags: sd-card, bus, standards

So I am confused about the SDXC read standards compatability. I understand that UHS-I/II/III/Express define bus interfaces and UHSII added a 2nd row of pins. UHSIII achieves higher speeds than that. Then there's U1/U3 which is about which is about minimum writing speeds as is V6 to V90. Then there's application performance class 1&2 which guarantees read and write input/output operations.

Now my question is: Which of these standards introduces new hardware dependencies? How can I find out if my device can leverage the full abilities of the SD card? Are the newer standards all backwards compatible so they can at least be used in older SDXC readers?

Comment: Thanks @music2myear for keeping the site clean but the reason hardware shopping recommendations are banned do not apply here. Naming a practical example in this case was very sensible and would not be outdated quickly. Asking which readers can leverage which standards is the same as asking which processors have which sockets...

Comment: Have a look at the datasheet. You already named one hardware change yourself. You're also mixing various attributes that, while all being relevant for SD cards, require a context in which you want to use them.

Comment: @Seth I did look at the datasheets, however I was unable to find out much more than SDR104 which as far as I understand it refers to the bus width? But then which features are supported? A1/A2? I'll be running an OS on the card and will replay some media from it from time to time as well. The SD Associations website does a good job at describing what the SD card standards mean but not at all how to verify compatability with hardware devices? Or can I simly assume that any SDXC device can leverage ALL features of all SDXC cards?

Comment: How old is your reader? Most SD card changes aren't recent developments but have been around for some years. Have a look at [this SanDisk article](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2520/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-specifications-and-compatibility). If you do have a SDXC compatible reader you should be able to read any SDXC card but not necessarily at its rated speed.

Comment: My reader is the built in SDXC Module built into the [ROCKPRO64](https://www.pine64.org/rockpro64/) which I had mentioned int he orignial post but it got put on hold because of the mention of a useful example. Were there absolutely no hardwarechanges between all the SDXC card readers? There must have been some for the 2nd pin row in UHSII right? Or is all you need to leverage the benefits of the speed standards like Application Performance Class 2 and UHS3 and U3 and V90 or are all of these just improvements to the card that can be leveraged via newer software alone?

Comment: Since we're down to hardware again, I can tell you what I found out: The sbc according to its datasheet supports MicroSDHC and MicroSDXC SDMMC SD3.0(SDR104) which as I understand it means UHSI is supported but UHSII isn't(which your link also confirms). But what about the other speed measures? Like Application Performance 1&2, V30 to V90(for write speeds) and U1/U3? Are these ONLY depending on software and I can just get something like [this](https://gzhls.at/i/89/57/1878957-n0.jpg) and be able to use all of the provided speed by that card?

Comment: [Wikipedia article on SD cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card), the application and video classes are just conventions as to what a card should be able to handle. Obviously your reader would need to be able to handle it as well. You already mentioned that the UHS/U also has some hardware implications.

Comment: So the answer is: If the SD-reader supports UHS2 it also supports UHS3 and UHS1 and can read/write any card at the max speed it can provide. If the reader can only do UHS1 that is not the case with UHS2/3.